# Error = OROCRM => server_name <your_domain_name> www.<your_domain_name>;

Tags: orocrm

I am trying to install ORO CRM in centos localhost, during installation what i need to put here -> `server_name <your_domain_name> http://www.<your_domain_name>;`

Comment: can you please expand your question? during what step of installation it asks you to fill server_name? I don't see this parameter anywhere in OroCRM install

Comment: @Ludo I am following this document -> https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/current/install-upgrade/installation-quick-start-dev/crm, at the stage of Configure Web Server : what i need to put here -> server_name <your_domain_name> www.<your_domain_name>; FYI -> i am installing by centos  LAMP localhost.

Comment: that is not related to OroCRM but to configuration of webserver, nginx can pass HTTP request to configured site based on URL, the value depends on what domain you want to run it http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: if you use LAMP stack, it means you want to run on Apache, so nginx config may be pretty irrelevant